# Problems with git and bundler

Tags: git, ruby

I'm trying to set up Gitorious on my Server [with this tutorial](http://cjohansen.no/en/ruby/setting_up_gitorious_on_your_own_server) and having problems over problems with gem/git. After fixing a lot of libs and dependancies, bundler now won't work with git repositories...
Whenever I'm trying to load the rails environment it fails:

```
Loading production environment (Rails 2.3.5)
https://github.com/roman/rots.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`
```

I'm using ruby 1.9.1 and changed all the RUBY_HOME variables I could find accordingly.
`Bundle install` doesn't have any problems: `Your bundle is complete!`

How can I get this to work?
It seems it's really just stuck with this git problem, it doesn't have any problems with gem that couldn't be fixed by installing missing libs

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-install bundler

```
gem remove bundler
gem install bundler
```

Then run it with debugging

```
bundle install --verbose
```

Also tell us the line it prints for 'rots' when installing. It should say

```
Using rots from git@...
```